# Wordpress - Group buying theme question

Tags: wordpress

I am using GBS theme (Group Buying Site theme) in my wordpress site.This theme has homepage,deals page(specific to this GBS theme) etc.,

is it possible to set deals page as my homepage? like if www.example.com is my website and
www.example.com/deals is my deals page.. is it possible to make this as starting page when user clicks www.example.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm not familiar with the particular theme. But in your admin panel go to "Settings" > "Reading". There you can configure what your frontpage displays.

If this doesn't work, you can always use a mod_rewrite rule to rewrite the home to the deals page.

Comment: do i need to use mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess file?

Comment: You don't need to, just set it in the admin panel where @Peter mentioned